# How can I run jQuery after an address update in Wordpress/Woocommerce?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress, Woocommerce and the plugin, WooReer (delivery cost by distance).

Goal:
Disable delivery option if it's too far and add messaging to let users know it's too far. (Delivery is also not available if the total is less than $30).

So far:

I've set a cost of $999,999 for delivery if it's outside of the delivery area and I want to replace that with some words like, 'Too far for delivery'.

I have a child theme and have some code that works - but it seems to only work when I refresh the cart page. I need to find a way to get it to work when a product quantity is updated on the cart page and when a delivery address is updated.

Here's my code:

shipping_method_0_local_pickup20 - the name of a radio input for local pickup
shipping_method_0_wcsdm16 - the name of a radio input for delivery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    var total = jQuery('.order-total').text().replace(',','').match(/(\d+)/g)[0];
    
    if(jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').prop('type') == 'hidden' & total >=30 ) {
        var newText = jQuery('.woocommerce-shipping-destination').parent().html().replace("Delivery address", "Enter delivery address");
        jQuery('.woocommerce-shipping-destination').parent().html(newText); 
    } else if(jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').prop('type') == 'hidden') {
        jQuery('.woocommerce-shipping-destination').hide();
        jQuery('.shipping-calculator-button').hide();
        jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').show();
        jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').prop('checked', true);
    } 
    else if(jQuery('#shipping_method_0_wcsdm16').parent().text().indexOf('999,999') != -1 ) {
        jQuery('#shipping_method_0_wcsdm16').hide();
        jQuery('#shipping_method_0_wcsdm16').parent().html('<b>Address too far for delivery</b>') ;
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing first,

1. I think in the first if statement, for AND statement you need to use '&&':

```js
if(jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').prop('type') == 'hidden' && total >=30 ) {
```

2. If you don't want to refresh page to see the change, you need to use ajax method, either with admin-ajax api or wp-rest api. Unfortunately, I don't think WooReer use ajax method to immediately update the delivery condition without refreshing. You can write them by yourselves (it's not that complicated), but if you think it's such a drag,
3. Some plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shipping-zones-by-drawing-for-woocommerce/) use ajax method to check address.

Now, some sidenotes:

- If you can, avoid jquery. It's so slow, and using javascript vanilla functions is not complicated nor a big inconvenience.
- Avoid using long-nested if statements. It won't help performance, but it'll make your code easier to read by yourself. Something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Do something
  if (document.querySelector('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup20').type != 'hidden' && document.querySelector('#shipping_method_0_wcsdm16').parentElement.text.indexOf('999,999') != -1 ) {
    // > Hide radio input
    // > Say address is too far
    return; // Escape from the code
  }
  // Type is hidden
  if (total >= 30) {
    // > Change the HTML of shipping destination
    return; // Again, escape
  }
  // Type is hidden and total < 30
  // > Hide shipping destination and calculator button, show local pickup
});
```

This de-nesting style will feel more natural over time.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That's helpful. My question is broader because even if I turn off WooReer plugin, I want to know how to action something after - for example - a product quantity is changed (through Ajax), which then updates the cart totals. Can you give me a little more direction with the APIs please?